# How to get the user's list of accounts in Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good day, the app can't get access to the user's list of accounts. "me/accounts" returns an empty array.

I have checked this by creating a test application in the user's account and opening access to "pages_show_list". I executed it in Graph API Explorer and got the list. However, through another application, I can't access the list of accounts, even though it has Advanced access for pages_show_list.

When logging in through Facebook, I request "pages_show_list, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_messages, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_engagement, public_profile". I have Advanced access to these permissions in my app.

When opening the Facebook login, it only requests the name and profile photo. Do I need to get any other permissions?

Comment: _"Do I need to get any other permissions?"_ - no, but you need to get the ones you tried to ask for, actually granted. And according to your description, that did not happen in the first place. In case you _had_ already granted these permissions before, the login dialog would not ask again - but then your request should be giving the desired result as well.

Comment: Before testing, I deleted the app in the Facebook user settings. This allowed the login window to appear with permissions again. But the essence is that it does not provide the right to choose pages and other accounts, as soon as you press continue, this window closes. Although it should be the opposite [link](https://share.kz/g2Gw)

Comment: What user is trying to login there, do they have a role in the app?

Comment: I have passed the company's verification and received advanced permissions for pages_show_list. And I am trying to get a list of pages from a user who does not have a role in the app.

Comment: And you are asking for the permissions correctly in your login dialog call?

Comment: `FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: "pages_show_list,instagram_basic,instagram_manage_comments,instagram_manage_messages,pages_manage_metadata,pages_messaging,read_page_mailboxes,business_management"});`

This code runs normally from my account, in which I have a role in the app, and requests the necessary permissions.

Comment: If it works for users with a role in the app, but not for those without - then something with your permission review status must not be right.